# Need help calling a class in a JButton in java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

This is a program that is part of a larger overall program. Just running a few test lines of codes just to make sure something works before I get 100 lines down. Kinda of new to programming. What I am trying to do is when the `JButton` in my swing program is pressed it does a variety of things, one is calling a class that takes the text from a `jTextField` and outputs it to a `Jpanel`. The problem I am getting an error saying symbol cannot be found. Here the part of the code that is relevant to my question. I am trying to get ( `Name test1 = new Name();` ) to run.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Test");
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame1.setSize(800,800);
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Test run, just checking");

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.add(label1);

        Name test1 = new Name();


        frame1.add(panel1);


 public String Name()
{

  String g = jTextField3.getText();

 return g;

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line , `public String Name()` will define a method in Java and not a class. You are using `new` for a method name , `Name test1 = new Name();` which is invalid, `new` is used to create an instance object of class.

You need to directly call method without `new` and type of `test1` would be a `String` not `Name`, `String test1 = Name();`